# The as.matrix function returns only 50 columns when writing vegdist results where i am supposed to get 202

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `dfWD_STAND` with the following structure:

| Site | Species1 | Species2 | Species3 | ... | Species46 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | ... | 0.0 |
| V2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.3 | ... | 0.0 |
| V3 | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0.3 | ... | 0.0 |
| ... | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0.3 | ... | 0.0 |
| V202 | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0.3 | ... | 0.0 |

The values are species counts normalised for ratio to get to a fraction of the whole community. I want to run a bray-curtis dissimilarity analysis, and that computes fine, but when I want to visualise it with `as.matrix` it does so only up untill column 50.

As from what I have seen from the documentation it should return the matrix just fine, but it's not. I verified whether the input data was in the correct format, and have no idea how to progress with this.

Relevant code:

```
distWD = vegdist(dfWD_STAND)
dfDIST_WD = as.matrix(distWD)
```

I expected to get a dataframe of 202 rows and 202 columns, but the output is a data frame of 202 rows and 50 columns. If both rows and columns were a diverging number I would assume the problems lies somewhere else, but since the rownumber is correct I'm a little stumped.

edit: The following code makes a dataframe with the same layout as my dataframe and runs the same analysis, also returning only 50 columns

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=9292, min=0, max=1), nrow=202))
distWD = vegdist(df) 
dfDIST_WD = as.matrix(distWD)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you edit your question to include reproducible data (ie, include the output of `dput(dfWD_STAND)`)? This will help us recreate the error and provide faster, better help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jp, that would give a very big amount of text to paste on the screen and i'm unfamiliar with a way to do it compactly. I found a way to make a random number filled dataframe that behaves the same way though, will post the code

Comment: Distances are computed between rows (in your example sites), not columns (in your example Species). Looks like you've 50 sites, so you get a 50x50 distance matrix, regardless of species (column) count. You might need to `t()`ransform your input data.

Comment: To add to that: i have 202 sites, which is why i expected 202x202 output. should have specified that in the table, sorry

Comment: Okay, i ran the code again today and it just worked out fine. Don't know why, don't know how, but it's solved

Comment: Why don't delete the question?